# Largest parallelopiped that can be fitted in a cylindrical container with a hemispherical lid.

Tags: geometry, volume

A cardboard box in the shape of a rectangular parallelepiped is to be enclosed in a cylindrical container with a hemispherical lid. If the total height of the container from the base to the top of the lid is $60$ centimetres and its base has radius $30$ centimetres, find the volume of the largest box that can be completely enclosed inside the container with the lid on.

I have been able to sketch a figure. If we call $h$ and $R$ to be the height and radius of the hemisphere respectively,  then we have $h+R=60$ and $R=30$ and so, $h=30.$ But apart from this, I am completely out of ideas, on how to proceed with this problem.

Comment: Just ot be sure : "hemisphere = half-sphere" ? Begin by giving names, $h$ for the cylinder height, and $R$ for the radius. What can you say about $h+R$ ? Therefore $h=?$, etc...

Comment: I think largest rectangular parallelepiped that would fit is a square prism. But I have no proof for that. If it is a square prism, I might have an answer.

Comment: I believe the question is asking about the shapes known as "rectangular solids" — the *very* special case of parallelepipeds that have all dihedral angles as right angles.

Comment: I dont get the reason for this downvote. If the downvoter please explain the reason behind this downvote, I would definitely try to resolve the issues! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the *rectangular parallelepiped* mentioned in the question is a *cuboid*:
[image: cuboid]

The  largest cuboid that would fit in a cylinder with hemispherical lid is a square prism:[image: square prism]

**Base of cylinder/hemisphere**:

[image: Base of cylinder/hemisphere]
Diagonal of the square the diameter of the circle. Hence, $BD = 60cm$

Side of square $=$ Diagonal/$\sqrt 2$

Hence, $DC = \frac{60}{\sqrt2}$

Rationalising the denominator, we get $DC = 30\sqrt2$

There are two parts two the square prism, the part that is inside the cylinder and the part that is inside the hemisphere.

**Volume of the part inside the cylinder**

Volume of square prism $= a^2h_1$

where $a$ is the side of the square and $h_1$ is the height of the square prism.

For the part inside the cylinder, $h_1$ is the height of the cylinder.

Height of the cylinder $=$ total height $-$ radius $= 60 - 30 = 30cm$

So, the volume of the part inside the cylinder $= {(30\sqrt2)}^2×30=54000cm^3$

**Volume of the part inside the hemisphere**
[image: Central cross section of the hemisphere]
Length of $QS$ is the length of the side of the square $=30\sqrt2$

$QR=\frac{QS}{2}=15\sqrt2$

$PR$ is the radius of the hemisphere $=30$

By the Pythagorean theorem, we get $PQ=15\sqrt2$

Here, $PQ$ is the height of the part inside the hemisphere.
$PQ=h_2$

Volume of the part inside the hemisphere $=a^2h_2={(30\sqrt2)}^2×15\sqrt2=27000\sqrt2cm^3$

**Total volume of the box**$=$ Volume of part inside the cylinder $+$ Volume of the part inside the hemisphere $$=54000+27000\sqrt2cm^3$$

Comment: Indeed, a nice approach! Thanks a lot! I do get it now...